# Free HFSS alternative to create geometry using python

Tags: python, software, electromagnetism

I am using a python script to create wirebond interfaces in Ansys HFSS. Variables define the board, wirebond, and package geometry.  To simulate a new wirebond, I just edit the geometry variables and run the script.

My problem is, I have to use the computer with HFSS (and it's expensive license) just to verify the geometry is correct. It would be great if I had some free software that I could use to verify the geometry specified by my python script is correct. This would allow me to edit the script on any computer and only use HFSS when I was ready to simulate.

The script uses the "hfss" python class to send geometry and simulation options to HFSS. The hfss class and all commands specific to hfss would obviously need to be removed if different software was used, but that's ok. The coordinates of a box are specified the same in HFSS as many other CAD programs. Since, the specific coordinates of each geometric shape are what I want to verify, I don't see a reason why I can't use an alternative software.

One alternate I have tried is Salome. Geometry can be created with python and the syntax to describe shapes is similar to HFSS. I also found a 3-D viewer from Ansys called "3-D Ansys CFD Viewer". Looking at the description, I believe it can only view images created in HFSS and does not allow new geometry to be created, but I'm not 100% sure.

I would appreciate any software suggestions or ideas that would allow me to break free from the computer with HFSS.

Comment: That depends on how much effort you want to put into visualization.  [VPython](http://www.vpython.org/) comes to mind.  Also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026134/python-3d-visualization-and-graphics).

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee I hadn't thought of just creating the geometry straight from python. Good point. Separate software might not even be needed. I'll give VPython a try.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggested in the comments [VPython](https://www.vpython.org/), I would look into [GMSH](http://gmsh.info/), which now offers [Python API](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Gmsh-API). It will allow you to create the model relatively easily (offering some primitives to build from), provide cross-platform visualization, and even subsequent meshing (if that is of any interest to you).